# How to compile SQLite for POCO on Ubuntu?

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu, poco-libraries

In Ubuntu, what is the correct method to compile and link SQL using the POCO supplied SQL source files?

under windows, I just had to point the include folders and it worked.

I am totally stuck here, everything else works on both platforms :)

here is the method so far;

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

cd poco-1.7.8p3-all/
./configure --sqlite-thread-safe=2 --omit=Data/ODBC,Data/MySQL,CppUnit/WinTestRunner --static --no-samples --no-tests
make
sudo make install
```

Result:

```
g++ -o server.run server.o tables.o -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -lPocoNet -lPocoJSON -lPocoFoundation  -lPocoData -pthread

server.o: In function `main':
server.cpp:(.text+0xb50): undefined reference to `Poco::Data::SQLite::Connector::registerConnector()'

tables.o: In function `init_Table_list()':
tables.cpp:(.text+0x4d2): undefined reference to `Poco::Data::SQLite::Connector::registerConnector()'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no external dependencies for SQLite - you are missing `-lPocoDataSQLite`.
Also, since MySQL is explicitly excluded, it seems there's no need for mysql client development package

Comment: excellent it worked!

...mostly.. until I added -ldl too...

it compiles, thanks Alex, excellent.

Comment: "since MySQL is explicitly excluded, it seems there's no need for mysql client development package" 

I don't understand the implications stemming from this statement.

Should I be using MySQL ?
Which engine is better at being thread-safe ?

Comment: From your question, it seems that you are installing mysql client - that is not needed for SQLite. The way SQLite and mysql operate is different - mysql database is managed by a separate server, while SQLite contains the whole database in one file. What you should use depends on your requirements and is outside the scope of this thread - I suggest to post another question on that.

Comment: I thought I had excluded MySql with my compile line:

./configure --sqlite-thread-safe=2 --omit=Data/ODBC,Data/MySQL,CppUnit/WinTestRunner --static --no-samples --no-tests

Comment: exactly my point - for some reason you are showing it installed (`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`) prior to that and I am pointing out that it is unnecessary in this context.